# How to check every request in pyramid for redirect?

Tags: python, redirect, pyramid

I want to redirect users to a change password page when their password expired.  I already setup a RequestFactory that takes the user.  Where do I put the redirecting part in Pyramid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but the usual way to redirect in Pyramid is to return an HTTPFound instance in your view function. I think you could also just raise it since it's an exception.

```
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound

def my_view(request):
    return HTTPFound('/new/location/to/redirect')
```

A good practice is to use `route_url` to build the url you are redirecting to.